# convert matlab m file into vhdl

Tags: matlab, vhdl, simulink

Iam trying to convert .m file of matlab into vhdl code. I know this topic has been discussed over the help forums, but still the literature did not proved to be fruitful.

Kindly can anyone help in this regard.

Thanks.

Comment: well What have you tried?

Comment: why vhdl?  you planning to synthesize hardware?

Comment: "Ben" yes, Iam planning for hardware (FPG)

Comment: Nicholas according to the literature I tried to convert it into simulink and then tried to convert into vhdl by xilinx but my version was old, it didnt worked out. Neither my simulink model.

Comment: no one can help without more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [HDL Coder](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/hdl-coder/) to generate VHDL code from a Simulink model (NB: Simulink model, not MATLAB code). I would suggest you get in touch with MathWorks as it's not a trivial exercise, they can advise you on the suite of toolboxes you need. It won't come cheap either... You will probably need to update your version/release of MATLAB.

Comment: am304, your NB is not correct. Recent versions of HDL Coder support generating HDL code directly from MATLAB code (as well as from Simulink models and Stateflow charts), although it's only a subset of the MATLAB language. +1, though, for the suggestion to get in touch with MathWorks - it's difficult to do this unless you have some advice from them.

Comment: @am304 Thanks for your reply and help. Appreciate it.